# Power query Error.Record

Tags: excel, error-handling, powerquery

How do I spit out records, to show up in the workbook queries pane as error records pls?

For example, if the [AcctClass] <> [_checkAcctClass] columns do not match, reject that record as an error

```
let 
    source = AccountIDsWithDuplicates,
    grouped = Table.Group(source, {"AcctID"}, {{"AcctClass", each List.Max([AcctClass]), type logical}, {"_checkAcctClass", each List.Min([AcctClass]), type logical}, {"Sum_Bal", each List.Sum([#"Bal_EUR"]), type number}}),
    // Make sure accounts only have one AcctClass 
    ErrorRecords = Table.SelectRows(grouped,  each([AcctClass] <> [_checkAcctClass])
in
    grouped
```

Answer (score 1):

Composing `Table.TransformRows` to create errors and then putting them back in a table with `Table.FromRecords` might do what you want?

```
= Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(grouped, each if [AcctClass] <> [_checkAcctClass] then error "didn't match" else _), Value.Type(grouped))
```

If the first row is an error then `Table.FromRecords` will completely break, but you can work around that by telling it what table type to expect.

Example mashup:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document("AcctID,AcctClass
        1,false
        1,true
        2,true
        2,true"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source),
    AccountIDsWithDuplicates = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"AcctID", Int64.Type}, {"AcctClass", type logical}}),
    grouped = Table.Group(AccountIDsWithDuplicates, {"AcctID"}, {{"AcctClass", each List.Max([AcctClass]), type logical}, {"_checkAcctClass", each List.Min([AcctClass]), type logical}}),
    ErrorRecords = Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(grouped,  each if [AcctClass] <> [_checkAcctClass] then error "didn't match" else _), Value.Type(grouped))
in
    ErrorRecords
```